# Reusing functional dependency as a type function

Tags: haskell

I have a typeclass that uses functional dependency and example instance:

```hs
class (KnownSymbol name) => MyClass name result | name -> result

instance MyClass "something" Int
```

How can I reuse this and get a type-level function `GetType` so that `GetType "something"` returns `Int`?

My unsuccessful attempt was pretty naive:

```hs
class CanGetType a b | a -> b where
  type GetType a

instance (MyClass name result) => CanGetType name result where
  type GetType name = result
```

which fails:

```
The RHS of an associated type declaration mentions out-of-scope variable ‘a’
  All such variables must be bound on the LHS
```

Comment: Though this is indeed a duplicate, I find the answer to that question hardly satisfying. Added a bounty there which will hopefully result in better ones.

Comment: I think this is a difficult question to answer properly because the simple answer is "it's not possible", but there's most likely a workaround for any specific thing you are actually trying to do. It's an XY problem except that, unlike typical XY problems, the Y problem is quite natural and theoretically interesting IMO. So you might have better luck with an answer by providing details about your use case.